# How to do a "passback" (Don't know the specific term)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Here is my code:

```
def function_one():
    print ("Hello!")
    choice = int(input("Would you like to see the list and the testvar? 1 = yes, 2 = no"))
    if choice == 1:
        #prints the list and testvar
    function_two()

def function_two():
    list = [1, 4, 7, 9]
    testvar = "Yes"
    function_one()

function_one()
```

How do I print testvar and list in function_one when I had already run it previously and run it later?

Comment: `function_one` doesn't have access to the local variables in the scope where it is called; either make `list` and `test_var` globals, or pass them as arguments.

Comment: This kind of mutual recursion isn't recommended (especially when it appears to be unterminated).

Comment: @chepner Mutual recursion is often useful, although unterminated mutual recursion like this is much less so.

Comment: I should have clarified, it isn't recommended in Python, where it just eats up limited stack space when you could use a loop instead.

Comment: Why don't you keep list and testvar in function_one and use for loop to ask for input?

Comment: Could someone explain how to do it in simple terms as I am a noob. I really don't want to have a loop but just to be able to print testvar and test_var in the most simple way possible, I don't mind about stack space as I don't know what it is.

Comment: Also I realised that I spelt would wrong in the code :)

Comment: Feel free to correct the spelling mistakes in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The type of behavior you describe is known as mutual recursion, and even well-implemented it's not recommended in Python. Recursion in general is best avoided in Python (unless the pitfalls of avoiding recursion are greater than the pitfalls in using it. "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds" and all that).

You SHOULD run `function_one`'s body in a continuous loop, then call `function_two` when applicable.

```
def function_one():
    while True:  # infinite loop
        print ("Hello!")
        choice = int(input("Would you like to see the list and the testvar? 1 = yes, 2 = no"))
        if choice == 1:
            # I'm guessing at your intended functionality here
            lst, testvar = function_two()
            print(lst, testvar)

def function_two():
    return ([1, 4, 7, 9], "Yes")
```

Comment: I don't understand with  while true, lst, testvar = function_two(). In your method, was list and testvar defined before the return? Also can I try doing it with the if statement leading to a new function which then prints them?

Comment: @TIC-FLY [hopefully this will help](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/0e9e185fef9ba2ea5932905ab05d039a) but note that this sort of explanation goes beyond what Stack Overflow is really used for. Sounds like you need a tutorial, not a Q&A site!